# Image from URL to stream

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm getting images from a url:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(article.ImageURL));
NLBI.Thumbnail.Source = image;
```

This works perfect, now i need to put it in a stream, to make it into byte array. I'm doing this:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
wb.SaveJpeg(ms, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
```

**And code fails with NullReference, how to fix it?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You get a `NullReference` exception because the image is still not loaded when you use it. You can wait to the `ImageOpened` event, and then work with it:

```
var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(article.ImageURL));               
image.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
    {
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        wb.SaveJpeg(ms, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
    };
NLBI.Thumbnail.Source = image;
```

Other option is to get the stream of the image file directly using WebClient:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
     {
         byte[] imageBytes = new byte[e.Result.Length];
         e.Result.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

         // Now you can use the returned stream to set the image source too
         var image = new BitmapImage();
         image.SetSource(e.Result);
         NLBI.Thumbnail.Source = image;
     };
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(article.ImageURL));
```

Comment: You should go for the second option. Download the image buffer by means of a `WebClient` as shown above, then write the stream to a byte array and directly create the BitmapImage from the same stream by calling [BitmapImage.SetSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsource(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: I have completed the answer with suggestion from @Clemens

Answer (score 38):

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(article.ImageURL);
```

Comment: `WebClient.DownloadData` is not available in Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks , but i get `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`

Comment: Worked for me in c# mvc with  .net 4.5.1

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
    private async Task<byte[]> GetImageAsByteArray(string urlImage, string urlBase)
    {

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlBase);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(urlImage);

        return await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    }
```

Comment: i think when i asked the question there was no such thing as async in windows phone 7 :)