# Image.FromFile FullURL is not working

Tags: c#, image, server.mappath

First, let me give codes

1)

```
if (dt.Rows.Count.ToString() != "0")
    {
        resimm = dt.Rows[0]["resim"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        resimm = "UserFiles/Image/no_image.jpg";

    }

    System.Drawing.Image orjinalFoto = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(resimm));
```

2)

```
 System.Drawing.Image orjinalFoto = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("http://www.example.com/UserFiles/Image/example.png");
```

A problem when using object 1, such as running, but when using the structure of 2, as the full URL "URI format not supported" error. Full URL `Image.FromFile` How can I object?

Comment: check if one of these help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071025/load-an-image-from-a-url-into-a-picturebox or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876015/image-from-url-to-stream

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem.

```
Server.MapPath(resimm)
```

change to

```
System.Net.WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://example.com/UserFiles/Image/Car/40-nissan-qashqai--sfmd-.jpg")).GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot write "~/" at the first of your url. So, you have to change

```
resimm = "UserFiles/Image/no_image.jpg";
```

To:

```
resimm = "~/UserFiles/Image/no_image.jpg";
```

Or write in this way:

```
Server.MapPath("~/UserFiles/Image/no_image.jpg");
```